# Reliable UK/EU ICMP Targets for Periodic Routing/Connectivity Tests?

Tags: routing, network-monitoring, testing, icmp

I need to test routing between my United States datacenters and United Kingdom and Mainland Europe ISPs. This is used to distinguish between general transcontinental routing issues and specific application issues and local network issues.

In the US, I'm aware of many reliable ICMP targets, such as `4.2.2.1`, `8.8.8.8`, `8.8.4.4`, or even `google.com`. Does anyone have recommendations for ICMP targets in the UK and Mainland Europe (to ping from the US) which are reliable and well-connected, and don't seem to frown upon pinging them every hour or so? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, google's DNS service (which is provided on the IP addresses you list above) is [anycast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast), which means there are systems all over the world that provide service on those addresses, and you get directed to the nearest one to you when you request it; their main website is similarly distributed.  Try `ping`ing `8.8.8.8` from the UK, and look at the RTTs - they'll likely be sub-30ms, so there's no way they're going transatlantic.  Do by all means ping them as a general connectivity check, but don't assume they're in the US.

So how to find an address to ping to check routing to a DC?  In my opinion, you should talk to the DC.  They know what parts of their infrastructure they use to participate in BGP routing; they will know which parts of their address space they will reliably present to the outside world by whichever the best-connected path is at any moment.  You have a contractual relationship with them, as you're hosting equipment with them, so they have some incentive to answer the question.  And if they're worried about someone pinging their core router once an hour, you know that they're sufficiently off-the-wall that you should find yourself a new DC.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. I should clarify that I want to ping a UK/EU address from the US, so `8.8.8.8` won't work for me in this case. Great idea on contacting my ISPs. Ideally, though, I'd be able to ping an upstream from my ISPs, as well as a couple of large ISPs in the EU as well, so I can isolate my EU datacenter's routing problems from my US datacenter's routing problems, if that makes sense.

Comment: My point is that `8.8.8.8` won't work for you in *any* case related to testing intercontinental links.

Comment: Right, got it, thanks! Currently, I don't need to do this back to the US, but when I do, I'll get something form the ISP as you suggested.